# How to remove dependency on peerJs server when using with Twilio turn/stun servers

Tags: twilio, webrtc, peerjs

I am using twilio from peerjs in my application. I had assumed that this removed dependencies on the peerjs server; the peerjs server has gone away at present which highlighted a dependency. Is it possible / how to remove this dependency?

My code is:

peer =  new Peer(myId, { secure: true,  config: iceServers: [twilio servers] }

results in:-

peerjs.min.js:52 WebSocket connection to 'wss://0.peerjs.com/peerjs?key=peerjs'.... failed:

I see that the 'host' parameter for the new Peer() call defaults to 0.peerjs.com, is there a Twilio replacement for this?

Comment: If you're looking for a Twilio replacement of PeerJS, there is [Twilio Video](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video) that provides signalling as well as other media capabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Twilio for STUN and TURN but that is *not* a drop-in replacement for the *signaling* server required by any WebRTC application. Hence peerjs will still attempt to connect to the "default" signaling server which is down per https://github.com/peers/peerjs/issues/937

Comment: I guess this means installing & running the peerjs server elsewhere. Thanks.